# Transforming a C++ executable to a library: how to prevent ending the process when returning from a call (eg: return instead of exit)

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I need to transform a C++ executable to a library, and avoid any call to `exit()` because the lifecycle of the library is managed by an external application, so I don't want the library process to end after a call to a function in this library.

This is a big application with lots of sources and `exit()` is called in quite a few places, including in void functions and functions that are called within other functions in the program.

For the moment, the only partial solution I see is to replace all calls to `exit()` by `return` but the problem is that some of these functions return `void` (so I can't do that) and I also have to check for behavior changes in the program, for example for functions that are called within the library itself.

I looked into `atexit()` but it doesn't let you shunt the exit behavior and replace it by a return behavior (and the atexit handler must be a void function anyway).

Is there any proper/simpler way to do that ?

Thanks

PS: I'm new in C/C+ development

**EDIT1**: I should add that the code must still be buildable as an executable and a library, depending on make options. I'm using macros in the code to allow that.

Comment: You can throw an exception? But the bigger issue is that the code was written with `exit` in mind, so the invariants the code relies on might not hold anymore so you cannot call any other functions. That might be why they called `exit` in the first place.

Comment: Why is functions returning `void` a problem? What prevents you from just doing a `return;` for those?

Comment: @spectras if I do that, how do I know in the caller that I used `return` instead of nothing in the callee ? I need to know, because I'd have to handle that case like an "exit".

Comment: If the code was written in such a way that functions with fatal errors call `exit` and you want to instead pass the information to the caller and let them handle it then you have a lot of refactoring to do either by returning error conditions or by throwing exceptions. There's no magic macro bullet that will fix this unless your plan is to simply ignore any error and end up with a completely unreliable library.

Comment: It is not a very good idea to use `exit()` in a C++ application but even worse in a library. Looks like unfortunately program was not written carefully so looks like you will have to spend time fixing this issue.

Comment: @raoulvolfoni *"if I do that, how do I know in the caller that I used return instead of nothing in the callee ?"* -- How is this a bigger problem in a `void`-returning function than in a value-returning function? Don't the callers of value-returning functions also need to know if the callee would have called `exit`? How do they do this in the case where all possible return values are potentially valid?

Comment: *"the only partial solution I see is to replace all calls to `exit()` by `return`"* -- I agree that this is at best a partial solution. However, my reasoning might be different than yours. The big part of the solution would be to define what should happen instead of exiting. Converting `exit` to `return` is only one piece. How should the call sites behave differently? Will they have to propagate the error condition up the call chain, or is there a recovery option? You might be able to standardize this somewhat, but potentially, each instance of `exit` will have a different preferred solution.

Comment: In a way I'm lucky because this is old code and the dev didn't use exceptions, only exit.

So I think I could quite easily replace all `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` with exceptions and catch them at the entry point of the lib.

Then I could try to replace all `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` with return. This would be more complicated and time consuming.

I could also use exceptions for EXIT_SUCCESS but that seems too dirty even for me.